Stripe API error: Missing required param: query
I am trying to use Pabbly to query my stripe account to obtain what customer ID is associated with a specific email. I am trying the standard "out of the box" query shown below, but keep getting the response "Missing required param: query"
Here's the cURL text from the stripe website:
curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/search \
  -u "sk_test_keyhere" \
  --data-urlencode query="email:'sally@rocketrides.io'"

Heres what the the screen looks like in Pabbly:


Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I've tried several variants of the text in the sample query but havent had any luck

"what customer ID is associated with a specific email." - You do know that Stripe customer e-mails are non-unique, right? How do you plan to handle multiple matches?

cURL's --data-urlencode sets the request to POST and also, cURL also handles the '@' char specially - both of those behaviours are likely causing you problems.

can you paste your full curl command with redacting key with XXXXX
